# Integer Array in Mysql Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql

How do i use integer values array in Mysql Stored procedure ?

Answer (score 3):

This helps for me to do IN condition
Hope this will help you..

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE `test`(IN Array_String VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM Table_Name
    WHERE FIND_IN_SET(field_name_to_search, Array_String);

END//;
```

Calling:

```
call test('3,2,1');
```

Answer (score 2):

if you want to pass to the stored procedure an array look at

[How can I pass an "array" of values to my stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404941/how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-values-to-my-stored-procedure)

and

http://www.coderanch.com/t/505422/Oracle-OAS/pass-Integer-Array-Stored-Procedure