# How can we pass array of objects to mysql stored procedure using jpa

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

How to pass array of object to mysql stored procedure using jpa.

We have class Tag which has tag_name, tag_url as attributes. How can we pass list/array of tags to mysql stored procedure using jpa/hibernate.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but no there is no way to do that using mysql, which is actually good because I don´t see a way were that would have a practical usage that couldn´t be solved by a better database model design or a improve in the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to use MySQL 5.1, it is not possible to pass in an array.
See the MySQL 5.1 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/faqs-stored-procs.html#qandaitem-27-4-17

for postgres refer following answer

[How can I pass an "array" of values to my stored procedure?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/404941/how-can-i-pass-an-array-of-values-to-my-stored-procedure)

Comment: I am using Server version: 10.2.7-MariaDB-10.2.7+maria~xenial-log mariadb.org binary distribution